# Is it ok to use std::shared_ptr<T*>?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

This problem has troubled me for a long time, please help me, thank you！

Question 1:

```
{
  {
    std::shared_ptr<int*> t1 = make_shared<int *>(new int(3));
  }
 // here t1 is point heap,when the t1 died,the heap of int(3) is not free
 // in stack is correct
 {
    std::shared_ptr<int> t1 = make_shared<int>(); 
  }
 // how to reslove this ? Is `std::shared_ptr<int* >,std::shared_ptr<string* > ...` is forbiden?
}
```

yes,i want to ponts a struct, but it does't work to call destructor，like this example

```
class DelTest
{
public:
    DelTest() {

        cout << " DelTest()" << ":" << i++ << endl;
    }

    ~DelTest() {

        cout << "~ DelTest()" << ":" << j++ << endl;
    }

};
void test()
{
   std::shared_ptr<DelTest*> t1 = make_shared<DelTest*>(new DelTest);
}
```

when the test has gone the ~DelTest() can't to work;I want use  `std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<DelTest*>> m;` to replace `std::map<int,   DelTest*> m`;

```
std::map<int,  std::shared_ptr<DelTest*>> m
for (auto it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it)
{
    m.erase(it);
}
```

~DelTest() it does't work

Comment: It does not make sense to me to have a `shared_ptr<T*>`; because then you have an owning shared_ptr object to a raw pointer where you have to manually manage its lifetime.  Better to have a `shared_ptr<unique_ptr<T>>` ... but if you have that why not just have `shared_ptr<T>` in the first place.

Comment: `std::shared_ptr<int*>` -> `std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int>>`

Comment: Do you want a shared pointer which points to a normal pointer? If that's what you want, then you want `std::shared_ptr<T*>`. Otherwise, you don't.

Comment: What gave you the idea to use `std::shared_ptr<DelTest*> t1 = make_shared<DelTest*>(new DelTest);` instead of `std::shared_ptr<DelTest> t1 = make_shared<DelTest>();` and `std::map<int,  std::shared_ptr<DelTest*>> m` instead of `std::map<int,  std::shared_ptr<DelTest>> m`?

Comment: I didn't figure out the difference between std::shared_ptr<T * >and std::shared_ptr<T  > so that would cause this problem

Comment: It's better to start with practical problem you are trying to solve, then give code. We can't infer your intent from your code.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it ok to use `std::shared_ptr<T*>`?

Depends on what you mean by OK. Is it well formed, and does it have well defined behaviour? Yes.

Do you need it? Maybe; probably not; depends on use case.

> ```
> std::shared_ptr<int*> t1 = make_shared<int *>(new int(3));
> ```

This is bad. Don't use owning bare pointers. You may forget to delete it, and cause a memory leak.

> ```
> std::shared_ptr<int> t3(new int[10], [](int*p) {delete[] p; });
> ```

Since C++17, use `std::shared_ptr<int[]>` instead. Otherwise consider using `std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int>>` for simplicity.

Comment: I test that 
 ``` 

    std::shared_ptr<int[]> t3(new int[10], [](int*p) {delete[] p; }); 
std::shared_ptr<int[]> t3 = std::make_shared<int[]>(new int[10], [](int*p) {delete[] p; }); 

```
is correct, so i guess \r\n ```   std::shared_ptr<int[]> t3(new int[10], [](int*p) {delete[] p; }); ``` is equal to ```   std::shared_ptr<int> t3(new int[10], [](int*p) {delete[] p; }); ``` right?

Comment: You don't need a custom deleter for `std::shared_ptr<int[]>`.

Comment: @eerorika -- you **do** need a custom deleter for `std::shared_ptr<int[]>` if you don't have C++ 17. And even then, some compilers don't support it.

Comment: @PeteBecker You couldn't use `std::shared_ptr<int[]>` at all prior to C++17, could you?

Comment: Well, you could use it, in the sense that nothing prohibits it, but it had no sensible semantics. My comment was a sloppy mashup of conflicting ideas; prior to C++17 you need a custom deleter to manage an array of `int` with `shared_ptr<int>`. Sorry for confusing things.